# How to serve ddeb files with reprepro?

Tags: apt, debug, reprepro

I maintain our internal apt repo of Ceph, its build script generations some `ddeb` files, which is the debug symbol file. But `reprepro` cannot add those ddeb files, with errors like:

> Unknown file type: 'a2e592c703334bc9f55a62f6fac267d8 135503940 debug optional ceph-base-dbgsym_14.2.7-75-g14b67dbc11-1_amd64.ddeb', assuming source format...

And below is my repo conf/distributions file:

```
Codename: bionic
Suite: stable
Components: main
Architectures: amd64 source
```

and `reprepro` version is 5.1.1

Answer (score 4):

There's an old bug about this [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730572).

I am currently using a forked version of reprepro from [here](https://github.com/ionos-enterprise/reprepro). This forked version was actually created to enable [multiple versions](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=570623) but also has support for ddeb files. It's not perfect and has some annoyances, primary being that the ddeb files are put into a special component. I opened a bug report about it [here](https://github.com/ionos-enterprise/reprepro/issues/15) that talks about how to configure your sources.list to get them to actually be available to install after adding them to the repo using the custom reprepro.